# How do I let the user move a circle into another circles by dragging it in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

At the start I want the user to see:

[image]

The then want to give the user the choice to be able to drag H or C into the circle, so that it looks like:

[image]

This means while the user drags the H into the circles the other items that are already in the circle are have to move to make space for it. Ideally I would want them to be evenly distributed in the bigger circle. To have a nice UX I want the transition between the two images to be visible.

How do I best implement this UI?

Comment: You can follow http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidDragAndDrop/article.html article for reference.

Answer (score 0):

the best way to do this is you use separate overlapping imageview to construct the big image and use separate imageview for each part image. then use imageview.setOnDragListener() for drag image and imgview.setOnTouchListener() to create shadow. study about this and you will definitely do it.